# Isomorphism between Ordered Sets

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, order-theory

The proof in [Proof Wiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Unique_Isomorphism_between_Finite_Totally_Ordered_Sets) states that the proofs for "empty mapping is mapping" and "mappings between sets of same cardinality are equivalent" imply that $\emptyset\in A$.

Why is that?
Can somebody give me an explanation for this, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A$ is the set of all $n\in\Bbb N$ such that if $S$ is any set of cardinality $n$, and $\preceq$ is any total order on $S$, then there is exactly one isomorphism from $\langle S,\preceq\rangle$ to $\langle\Bbb N_n,\le\rangle$. We want to show that $\varnothing\in A$.

The only set $S$ of cardinality $0$ is $\varnothing$, and the result [Empty Mapping Is Mapping](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Empty_Mapping_is_Mapping) says that $\varnothing$ is a mapping from $\varnothing$ to any set. In particular, it’s a mapping from $\varnothing$ to $\Bbb N_0$. In the notation used in your source $\Bbb N_0$ is the set of natural numbers less than $0$, so $\Bbb N_0=\varnothing$: $\varnothing$ is a mapping from $\varnothing$ to $\varnothing$.

This mapping is surjective: $\forall x\in\Bbb N_0\,\exists y\in\varnothing(\langle y,x\rangle\in\varnothing)$ is vacuously true simply because there is no $x\in\Bbb N_0$. The result [Equivalence of Mappings between Sets of Same Cardinality](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_Mappings_between_Sets_of_Same_Cardinality) then says that this mapping is bijective, since its domain $\varnothing$ and range $\Bbb N_0$ are clearly of the same cardinality: they’re even the same set.

We now have a bijection from $\varnothing$ to $\Bbb N_0$, namely, the mapping $\varnothing$. It is vacuously order-preserving: the only total order on $\varnothing$ is $\varnothing$, which is also the only total order on $\Bbb N_0$, and since $\varnothing$ has no members, there’s simply nothing to check. Thus, the map $\varnothing$ is an order-isomorphism from $\langle\varnothing,\varnothing\rangle$ to $\langle\Bbb N_0,\le\rangle$ (where in this case $\le$ turns out to be just $\varnothing$).

Finally, any order-isomorphism from $\langle\varnothing,\varnothing\rangle$ to $\langle\Bbb N_0,\le\rangle$ is a subset of $\varnothing\times\Bbb N_0$, and $\varnothing$ is the only subset of $\varnothing\times\Bbb N_0$, so $\varnothing$ must be the only order-isomorphism from $\langle\varnothing,\varnothing\rangle$ to $\langle\Bbb N_0,\le\rangle$. This shows that the map $\varnothing$ satisfies the requirements for membership in $A$.

Comment: and why is it the case, that " is the set of all ∈ℕ such that if  is any set of cardinality , and ⪯ is any total order on , then there is exactly one isomorphism from ⟨,⪯⟩ to ⟨ℕ,≤⟩."?

Comment: @Ikey: That is simply the definition of the set $A$. The argument that follows the definition is a proof that $A=\Bbb N$.